# What is name of vertices order property?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I'm trying to find the next vertices on polyline using python script in order to calculate the angle between them.

What is the name of vertices order property ?

Vertices have an attribute for X,Y and for his number- at polyline the number  is also the sequence of the vertices.

How can I use this property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no attribute or property in arcpy that denotes the numbering of the vertices. Luckily, it's fairly straightforward to attach the numbering. For flattening a list of lists, there is a great Stack Overflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) and for Counter, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python).

Not terribly efficient, and there is likely a much easier method out there, but it does the job:

```
import itertools, collections, arcpy

fc = "<path to feature class>"

#OID is needed to separate features.
verts = [[row[0], row[1].firstPoint.X, row[1].firstPoint.Y] 
         for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"], explode_to_points=True)]

oid = zip(*verts)[0]

#Get number of vertices per feature by counting OID occurences.
#Equivalent to [oid.count(x) for x in xrange(1, len(set(oid))+1)], but should be faster.
vertnum = [x[1] for x in dict(collections.Counter(oid)).items()]  

#Flatten list of lists containing vertex numbering so it can be easily added.
flat = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((list(xrange(x)) for x in vertnum)))

#Add vertex numbering to original list of lists at position 0.
#Final list of lists will be [[vertex 0, OID, x, y], [vertex 1, OID, x, y]......].
[verts[x].insert(0, y) for x,y in enumerate(flat)]
```